# Насколько приемлемым будет вызов прайват членов класса внутри лямбды

Tags: c++

доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, на сколько приемлемым (не приемлемым) будет вызов прайват членов класса внутри лямбды, объявленной внутри одной из функций. Дабы быть более конкретным, ниже привожу тестовый код описывающий мой вопрос.

```
class A
{
public:

    void print_num(int num)
    {
        auto printer = [&](int num)
        {
            if (num <=5)
                std::cout<<_sqrt(num)<<"\n";

            else
                std::cout<<"more then 5";
        };

        printer(num);
    }

private:
    int _sqrt(int num)
    {
        return  pow(num,2); 
    }

};
```

Comment: В каком плане **приемлимым**? Вы имеете в виду производительность, философию хорошего тона, или же что-то другое?

Comment: @selya - философию хорошего тона.

Comment: В таком случае я не совсем понимаю, какой смысл использовать лямбду внутри функции. Если вы передаете эту лямбду куда-то в качестве коллбэка - то это вполне приемлимо. Если вы просто создаете ее внутри другой функции и вызываете - возникает только вопрос - зачем?

Comment: @selya Это я в качестве примера написал так. В моем проекте, я сделал класс который управляет стеком луа как разделяемым ресурсом и туда передаю лямбды, а далее жджу от него ответа... 
Код то компилируются, однако когда пишу лямбду, не вижу в интелесценсе используемые прайват методы (но сам код аналогичен приведенному, за минусом того что в данном коде я не куда эту лямбду не передаю). По этому и возник вопрос, возможно не даром не видно прайват методы когда пишу лямбду...

Comment: Краткий ответ - да приемлемо. Это как за хлебушком сходить, ежедневная рутина.

Comment: @selya пример насчёт зачем:
[пример](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9079217) - обычный pastebin забанен на работе, а как нормально код в комментарий вставить я не понял

Comment: @vegorov ну это один из пришедших мне в голову вариантов. Но согласитесь, что в большинстве случае вуществуют более элеганиные решения. В случае этого примера - просто объединить if. Суть примера я уловил, да. Но я думаю, что это уже больше какой-то js-style, я так редко пишу...

Comment: @selya я просто выношу повторяющийся код внутри некоторого метода класса в лямбда выражения, когда нет смысла делать это отдельной функцией (не понадобится в других методах класса)